# new to windev mobile app.how to remove the tag version express from windows

Tags: windev

I donwloaded windev mobile.I downloaded the express version.This is my first time ever working with this tool.I have a question though
 Will the tag "express version" be there until i get the full version.Isn't there a way to remove it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. WinDev Mobile Express is not meant to be used to create applications that are going to be delivered. So they add the tag to encourage users to buy the full version.

Answer (score 0):

True,

You can check power of Windev Mobile and create unlimited application without any restrictions. The only restriction is nag screen that reminds you for trial version.

I highly recommend you to go for WX